# How to put radio button next to the text? - Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

[image]

I would like to align each button next to each text above, but I am kinda stuck.

**Each **button + text** remains in a column. What I want is the individuals being aligned in a row.**

Here is the code from the image above:

```
Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Radio(
                    value: 1,
                    groupValue: id,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        predominant = 'recessiva_aa';
                        id = 1;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'Epistasia Recessiva (aa)',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
                  ),
                  Radio(
                    value: 2,
                    groupValue: id,
                    onChanged: (val) {
                      setState(() {
                        predominant = 'recessiva_bb';
                        id = 2;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                  const Text(
                    'Epistasia Recessiva (bb)',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
                  ), 
                  // ...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use radio list tiles. They have a title text widget.

```
RadioListTile(
 title: Text('This Works!'),
 value: true,
 groupValue: //your group value,
 onChanged: (value) {
 //someLogic;
 }),
```

Answer (score 2):

you can wrap your `Radio` and `Text`in a `Row`, something like

```
Row(
  children: [
    const Text(
      'Epistasia Recessiva (aa)',
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17.0),
    ),
    Radio(
      value: 2,
      groupValue: id,
      onChanged: (val) {
        setState(() {
          predominant = 'recessiva_bb';
          id = 2;
        });
      },
    ),
    // more widgets ...
  ]
),
```